# How to position an input at the bottom left of it's own div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I place an `input` and its 'Add' `button` at the bottom of their own `div`? I want to use either Bootstrap 4 or pure CSS. I tried position relative, absolute, fixed bottom, etc etc. None of those satisfied me.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container w-25">
  <div class='header'>
    <input class='mt-50' type='text' id='myInput' placeholder='Add a to-do'>
    <button type='button'>Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how did you try, but it's working. https://jsfiddle.net/x8scwa2j/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header {
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>PeyoToDo</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="todo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container w-25">
    <div class='header'>
        <input class='mt-50' type='text' id='myInput' placeholder='Add a to-do'>
        <button type='button'>Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers with no explanation are generally bad. Also, your snippet does not do what OP asks.

Comment: What is the OP asking? From what I understood he needs the contents of that div to be at the bottom of it's container.

Comment: Title: How to position an input at the bottom **left** of it's own div.

Comment: The CSS provided is giving exactly that. His input and buttons are at the bottom of the .header div and they are left aligned inside of it. That is what the user asked.

Comment: No, it does not. You are using `align-items: flex-end;` which by default in a flex div, is defined as a `flex-direction: row;`. Because it's a row, aligning items to `flex-end` merely pushes them to the bottom.

Comment: That's right, it pushes the input and button at the bottom. That is what the user wanted. But if you inspect the .header div you will find them at the bottom of .header and aligned left, because alignment left is the default.

Comment: Apologies, didn't see the `w-25` against the container. When you run your snippet it is in fact, dead centre.

Comment: You are forgiven for not seeing. Especially with a username as yours. LoL !

Comment: @swonder If you downvoted the answer, maybe now you could upvote it. Just saying :)